# Disable keyboard shortcuts on GitHub?

Tags: github, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm especially interested in disabling "T" button.

Comment: What page are you on for T?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise At least on every "repository" page. For example here: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent . I haven't noticed before, it's shortcut for "file finder"

Comment: I use search-as-you-type to find things in my editors and on github pages, it's really annoying when it jumps me off the page i'm on and onto the "find a file" screen because i pressed 't'.

Comment: [In Firefox it looks like this'll work.](http://superuser.com/questions/399352/how-do-i-prevent-pages-i-visit-from-overriding-selected-firefox-shortcut-keys)

Comment: @TomWoodward thx, looks like it will work everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically copying answer from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/595885/218497) linked by [Tom Woodward](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/103367/tom-woodward) in comments. I've only changed keycode and url.

It's Greasemonkey script which disables "T" shortcut. Supported by major browsers (extension like Greasemonkey for Firefox/Tampermonkey for Chrome may be needed/useful).

```
// Your code here...

// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable keyboard shortcuts
// @description    Stop websites from highjacking keyboard shortcuts
//
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *github.com*
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

keycodes = [84] // Keycode for 'T', add more keycodes to disable other key captures

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
//    alert(e.keyCode); //uncomment to find out the keycode for any given key
    if (keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1)
    {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This answer is outdated, there is now an easier way to do this through GitHub Accessibility settings, I've added a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify janot's answer (I can't add comments) use `e.key` instead of `e.keyCode`, then you don't need to figure out keycodes at all and instead can just list your `keys = ['t']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable keyboard shortcuts that don't use a modifier key (`Ctrl` or `Cmd`) in the [GitHub Accessibility settings](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/managing-accessibility-settings#managing-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: I thought this answer was a totally different approach to the accepted answer so would not be suitable to edit it. Can you link me to where the forum policy states link-only answers are bad?

Comment: [edit] "your" answer, not the accepted answer.  See [answer]:  *"Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible."*. [This Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/) also has some related content

Comment: SE sites are not forums. Even as an experienced SE user, if you never have, it would be valuable on each  site to take the [Tour] and review [ask] and [answer].  While I expect the "link only" issue is pretty common, other guidelines will vary. You are automatically given 100 reputation when you join new sites based on your SE "experience".  In turn you should be familiar with how the sites work, and willing to access readily available documentation like [answer].

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut feature related code is in this JavaScript file:

`https://github.githubassets.com/assets/environment-bootstrap-63ce95f0.js`

You can use a browser ad block extension and disable this URL: 
`https://github.githubassets.com/assets/environment-bootstrap*`

This will completely disable the shortcut feature.